# Sharing tweening or particle classes among multiple external .SWFs

Tags: actionscript-3, class, flash, external

Hopefully someone can help with this, I can't find the answer anywhere!

I'm currently building a flash project that consists of a main .SWF and multiple external .SWFs that are loaded as required.

Each of these requires a particle or tween class that assists with the animation, but bundling the classes with the .SWF increases the filesize considerably, and it would be inefficient to redownload these classes with each file.

Is there any way I could share these classes as a single file that can be used by the external .SWF files and only be downloaded once?

Thanks!
Edd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you need to use - [Runtime Shared Libraries](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7fd1.html)

Comment: @EddCoates - can you mark me as the answer please? the little tick needs clicking :)